# map 2 array of object using findIndex es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 array of object, one is the preloaded list, one is the selected items. My problem is couldn't make the selected items checked on checkboxes.

https://jsfiddle.net/8usvfzv9

```
class HelloWidget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.list = [{
        "id": "exhibitions",
        "name": "Exhibitions"
      }, {
        "id": "festivals_n_concerts",
        "name": "Festivals & Concerts"
      }, {
        "id": "grand_opening",
        "name": "Grand Opening"
      }, {
        "id": "meeting",
        "name": "Meeting"
      }, {
        "id": "party",
        "name": "Party"
      }, {
        "id": "product_launches",
        "name": "Product Luanches"
      }, {
        "id": "roadshows",
        "name": "Roadshows"
      }, {
        "id": "sporting_events",
        "name": "Sporting Events"
      }, {
        "id": "trade_show",
        "name": "Trade Show"
      }]

      this.selectedList = [{
        "id": "grand_opening",
        "name": "Grand Opening",
        "space_event_id": "grand_opening"
      }, {
        "id": "trade_show",
        "name": "Trade Show",
        "space_event_id": "trade_show"
      }]
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
        {this.list.map(obj => <div><br /><input 
        key={obj.name}
        checked={this.selectedList.findIndex(o => o.id === obj.id)}
        type="checkbox" >{obj.name}</input></div>)}
        </div>
        )
        }
}
```

I think this line is wrong

`checked={this.selectedList.findIndex(o => o.id === obj.id)}`

base on the output result. Any clue how to use findIndex?

Answer (score 0):

As 'checked' prop only works with boolean and [findIndex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp) returns number, you can modify as below:

```
checked={this.selectedList.findIndex(o => o.id === obj.id) !== -1}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Badacadabra. Accept~